# How can I scrape the table stats?

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

Here is the link I am trying to scrape: https://stats.nba.com/teams/traditional/?sort=W_PCT&dir=-1

So when I do this:

```
def roster(URL):
     res = requests.get(url)  
     text = res.text  
     soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(text, 'html.parser')
     print (soup)
```

the HTML I scraped down would not contain the actual table. For example, I am looking for the:

```
<div class="nba-stat-table__overlay" fata-fixed="2" role=grid">
```

So how can I actually find that? Please help!

Comment: Try getting the tags by its class name of the tag if the class name doesn't change. `soup.findAll("div", {"class": "nba-stat-table__overlay"})`

Comment: So when I go on the webpage, and click inspect, it will not show the class I want. Only if I click the table, it will find the class. Why is that?

Comment: The page is using angularjs framework and the table data which we're looking for is a lazy loaded component after the main page is loaded which is why its not coming in the response. 

There are two options now. Either scrape it using selenium kind of thing or get the URL which returns the stats of the table from the network section of dev tools if possible.

Comment: Ok. Can you please suggest some websites or videos I should read or watch to help me get my goals?

Answer (score 0):

Open the page with Selenium and then feed in the html source into pandas to parse the table.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import pandas as pd

driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://stats.nba.com/teams/traditional/?sort=W_PCT&dir=-1')

df = pd.read_html(driver.page_source)[0].dropna(axis=1)

driver.close()
```

**Output:**

```
print (df)
    Unnamed: 0                    TEAM  GP   W   L  ...  BLK  BLKA    PF   PFD   +/-
0            1         Milwaukee Bucks  65  53  12  ...  6.0   4.6  19.2  21.3  11.3
1            2      Los Angeles Lakers  63  49  14  ...  6.8   3.7  20.6  21.4   7.4
2            3         Toronto Raptors  64  46  18  ...  4.9   5.3  21.5  20.0   6.5
3            4             LA Clippers  64  44  20  ...  5.0   4.9  22.0  22.8   6.5
4            5          Boston Celtics  64  43  21  ...  5.6   5.6  21.4  20.6   6.2
5            6          Denver Nuggets  65  43  22  ...  4.6   4.5  20.0  20.0   3.0
6            7               Utah Jazz  64  41  23  ...  4.0   4.6  20.0  20.6   3.2
7            8              Miami Heat  65  41  24  ...  4.5   4.2  20.4  21.5   3.2
8            9         Houston Rockets  64  40  24  ...  5.1   4.9  21.6  20.8   3.8
9            9   Oklahoma City Thunder  64  40  24  ...  5.0   4.1  18.8  22.8   2.5
10          11          Indiana Pacers  65  39  26  ...  5.1   4.5  19.6  18.6   1.9
11          11      Philadelphia 76ers  65  39  26  ...  5.4   3.9  20.6  20.3   2.2
12          13        Dallas Mavericks  67  40  27  ...  5.0   4.0  19.0  20.8   6.0
13          14       Memphis Grizzlies  65  32  33  ...  5.6   5.3  20.8  19.7  -1.1
14          15           Brooklyn Nets  64  30  34  ...  4.6   5.3  20.7  20.9  -0.6
15          16           Orlando Magic  65  30  35  ...  5.7   4.8  17.6  19.2  -1.0
16          17  Portland Trail Blazers  66  29  37  ...  6.2   5.0  21.4  19.7  -1.6
17          18    New Orleans Pelicans  64  28  36  ...  5.1   4.8  21.0  20.6  -0.8
18          18        Sacramento Kings  64  28  36  ...  4.2   4.3  21.9  19.3  -1.9
19          20       San Antonio Spurs  63  27  36  ...  5.5   4.4  19.2  19.7  -1.8
20          21            Phoenix Suns  65  26  39  ...  4.0   5.6  22.1  22.8  -1.4
21          22      Washington Wizards  64  24  40  ...  4.3   5.0  22.6  22.4  -4.0
22          23       Charlotte Hornets  65  23  42  ...  4.1   5.0  18.8  20.6  -6.8
23          24           Chicago Bulls  65  22  43  ...  4.1   5.9  21.8  19.2  -3.1
24          25         New York Knicks  66  21  45  ...  4.7   5.0  22.2  19.8  -6.5
25          26         Detroit Pistons  66  20  46  ...  4.5   5.6  19.7  19.8  -3.6
26          27           Atlanta Hawks  67  20  47  ...  5.1   6.4  23.1  21.0  -8.0
27          28  Minnesota Timberwolves  64  19  45  ...  5.7   5.5  21.4  21.6  -4.3
28          29     Cleveland Cavaliers  65  19  46  ...  3.2   6.3  18.3  19.6  -7.9
29          30   Golden State Warriors  65  15  50  ...  4.6   4.9  20.1  20.1  -8.7

[30 rows x 28 columns]
```